# Is the regularization term necessary when classifying one feature?

Tags: classification, regularization, loss-functions, stochastic-gradient-descent

I'm using the `Stochastic Gradient Descent` linear classifier (implemented in Scikit-learn) to classify an image pixel by pixel. So my dataset has only one feature, which is the pixel intensity. The loss function I've used is the `hinge loss` function (L). R is the regularization term (penalty):

$$\omega = \omega - \eta \left[ \alpha \frac{\partial R(\omega)}{\partial \omega} + \frac{\partial L(\omega^T x_i + b, y_i)}{\partial \omega} \right]$$

After trying to alter some of the most basic parameters of this classifier (loss function, max_iters), I started wondering if in this case where the dataset has only one feature, whether it is necessary to add a regularization term to avoid the over-fitting?

In other words, would the model possibly over-fit when the training dataset has only one feature?

**Edit:**

As it is implemented in Scikit-learn (and as I understand it), in the `SGDClassifier` the objective is to end up with a linear model under the form:

$$ y = \omega x + b$$

During the classification of the test dataset, $x$ represent the intensity of the pixel, while $y$ is the class predicted:

$$y > 0 => class_1$$
$$y < 0 => class_2$$

The values of the two parameters $(\omega, b)$ are optimized with the first expression (Standard Gradient Descent). They are intialized with random values in the beginning. The only difference between `SGDClassifier` and the standard `Gradient Descent` is that the training is performed on a single instance of the dataset, which makes it quicker.

Comment: Wouldn't you have many features, one intensity feature *for exch pixel*?

Comment: What kind of other feature can be added in this case (binary classification)?

Comment: I suppose I'm not following.  Is the goal to classify the image as one of two classes based on the intensity of the pixels?

Comment: Exactly, the intensity of the pixel is one unique feature since the classification is performed on a single image band.

Comment: So don't you have multiple pixels in an image, and each pixel's intensity is one feature?

Comment: I think we're not using the same terminology. The feature is the pixel intensity, and the training dataset has thousands of samples (pixels intensities).

Comment: Stochastic Gradient Descent isn't a classifier, it's an optimization method. Can you clarify what you're doing?/

Comment: @Sycorax just added an update.